# Perl: search for a string in a list, then another string below/after it

Tags: regex, perl, list

I have a list as follows:

```
Policy Name:       PTCC-VNX7500-server_4A
Options:           0x0
template:          FALSE
Schedule:              MonthlyFull
  Type:                FULL (0)
  Calendar sched: Enabled
    Allowed to retry after run day
    Last day of month
  Maximum MPX:         1
  Synthetic:           0
  Retention Level:     11 (3 years)
```

for which I need to extract "Schedule:"
     (i.e. Schedule:              MonthlyFull)

... and then "Retention Level:"
     i.e.   Retention Level:     11 (3 years)
... wherever this string ("Retention Level:") shows up below the word "Schedule:".

I want to wind up with something that looks like this:

```
PTCC-VNX7500-server_4A,MonthlyFull,11 (3 years)
PTCC-VNX7500-server_4A,WeeklyFull,8 (4 weeks)
PTCC-VNX7500-server_4A,7_Year,1 (7 years)
```

I've tried to find the solution here and in Perlmonks but haven't been successful.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume by your expected output that you have several records of `Schedule`. Does `Policy Name` also change?

Comment: Good question!  Schedule changes, but the policy name remains the same.  Ultimately I will be looping through each "Policy Name" and looking for the schedule name and its associated Retention Level.

Comment: Can you show the whole list?  It seems we are missing a couple schedule items.  Also, do we need to look at multiple policies at once?

Comment: well, it's going to look pretty darn similar to what I showed as an example earlier.  Basically, there will be a total of three entries for each: 
Policy_Name1,Schedule1,Retention_Level1
Policy_Name1,Schedule2,Retention_Level2
Policy_Name1,Schedule3,Retention_Level3
Policy_Name2,Schedule1,Retention_Level1
Policy_Name2,Schedule2,Retention_Level2
Policy_Name2,Schedule3,Retention_Level3
... and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify this, but *assuming* each schedule is under a new policy name, you can use [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/nT9xH9):

```
Policy Name:\s*([^\n]+).*?Schedule:\s*([^\n]+).*?Retention Level:\s*([^\n]+)
```

This checks for `Policy Name:` followed by 0+ whitespace characters, and then captures everything up to the new line.  Next it lazily matches any amount of characters until `Schedule:` followed by 0+ whitespace characters, and then captures everything up to the new line.  Finally, it (surprisingly?) lazily matches any amount of characters until `Retention Level:` followed by 0+ whitespace characters, and then captures until the new line.

As seen in the linked example, this gives you 3 groups containing the policy name, schedule, and retention level.  You will need the global modifier (`g`) to match more than one policy at a time, the dot match new line modifier (`s`) to let `.*` match the line breaks, and optionally the case-insensitive modifier (`i`).

---

If there are multiple schedules are under one policy name, you can use [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/rW6aY7):

```
(?:Policy Name:\s*([^\n]+).*?)?Schedule:\s*([^\n]+).*?Retention Level:\s*([^\n]+)
```

This is very similar, we just wrap the whole `Policy Name:\s*([^\n]+).*?` section in a non-capturing group and make it optional.  This means that it does *not* need to be matched.  So the first match will have 3 capture groups (1: policy, 2: schedule, 3: retention), and subsequent matches may only have 2 capture groups (1: *null*, 2: schedule, 3: retention).  You would then use your language of choice to determine that match's policy name (from the previous match).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @rec;

while(my $line=<DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ /Policy Name:|Schedule:|Retention Level:/) {
        chomp($line);
        my ($name, $value) = split /:\s*/, $line;
        push @rec, $value;
        if ($line =~ /Retention Level/) {
            local $"=",";
            print "@rec\n";
            @rec = ();
        }
    } 
}
__DATA__
Policy Name:       PTCC-VNX7500-server_4A
Options:           0x0
template:          FALSE
Schedule:              MonthlyFull
  Type:                FULL (0)
  Calendar sched: Enabled
    Allowed to retry after run day
    Last day of month
  Maximum MPX:         1
  Synthetic:           0
  Retention Level:     11 (3 years)
Policy Name:       PTCC-VNX7500-server_4A
Options:           0x0
template:          FALSE
Schedule:              WeeklyFull
  Type:                FULL (0)
  Calendar sched: Enabled
    Allowed to retry after run day
    Last day of month
  Maximum MPX:         1
  Synthetic:           0
  Retention Level:     8 (4 weeks)
```

#### Output:

```
PTCC-VNX7500-server_4A,MonthlyFull,11 (3 years)
PTCC-VNX7500-server_4A,WeeklyFull,8 (4 weeks)
```

Comment: thank you so much!  That worked beautifully ... and more importantly, now I know how to do it myself next time.

Comment: @tyoung13 You're welcome. If it helped, please don't forget to click the tick mark next to the answer so that it is green.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my %record;
my $last_key;

while(<DATA>) {
    if (/^\s*(.*?):\s*(.*)/) {
        my ($k, $v) = ($1, $2);
        if ($k eq 'Policy Name' && %record) {
            print join(',', @record{('Policy Name', 'Schedule', 'Retention Level')}), "\n";
            %record = ();
        }
        $record{$k} = $v;
    }
}

print join(',', @record{('Policy Name', 'Schedule', 'Retention Level')}), "\n";

__DATA__
Policy Name:       PTCC-VNX7500-server_4A
Options:           0x0
template:          FALSE
Schedule:              MonthlyFull
  Type:                FULL (0)
  Calendar sched: Enabled
    Allowed to retry after run day
    Last day of month
  Maximum MPX:         1
  Synthetic:           0
  Retention Level:     11 (3 years)
Policy Name:       PTCC-VNX7500-server_123
Options:           0x0
template:          FALSE
Schedule:              SometimesEmpty
  Type:                FULL (0)
  Calendar sched: Enabled
    Allowed to retry after run day
    Last day of month
  Maximum MPX:         1
  Synthetic:           0
  Retention Level:     41 (8 years)
Policy Name:       PTCC-VNX7500-server_789
Options:           0x0
template:          FALSE
Schedule:              AlwaysBusy
  Type:                FULL (0)
  Calendar sched: Enabled
    Allowed to retry after run day
    Last day of month
  Maximum MPX:         1
  Synthetic:           0
  Retention Level:     17 (2 years)
```

Outputs:

```
PTCC-VNX7500-server_4A,MonthlyFull,11 (3 years)
PTCC-VNX7500-server_123,SometimesEmpty,41 (8 years)
PTCC-VNX7500-server_789,AlwaysBusy,17 (2 years)
```